# Need Help Sorting Array with Timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, timestamp

I have done my fair share of research before posting this and I now need a hand in the right direction. I have a list of ip camera filenames. The filenames are the timestamps itself that I need to sort. I cannot figure out how to sort the dates on the string names. I am thinking I need to convert the string to a readable format for the function `strtotime()` ? Or is there a way without changing the string? I have no clue how to approach this problem correctly.

I have tried `array_multisort($array, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC);` with no luck.

```
$array = Array ( 'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_18_11_05_62777.jpg', 'SNAP_CH01_2016_05_15_18_05_38_63588.jpg', 'SNAP_CH02_2016_05_15_18_05_13_38387.jpg', 'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_15_55_28_52502.jpg',  'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_14_52_46_26039.jpg',  'SNAP_CH03_2016_05_15_14_52_39_18421.jpg',  'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_14_51_34_19005.jpg', 'SNAP_CH02_2016_05_15_14_51_25_9874.jpg', 'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_06_12_49_23707.jpg', 'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_05_03_09_38176.jpg',  'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_03_33_27_29791.jpg', 'SNAP_CH03_2016_05_15_01_59_29_27941.jpg' );
```

Any advice is appreciated. Trying to learn.

Comment: Does it have to be sorted by the filename (including SNAP_CH04...) or just the timestamp portion? If just the filename, you should be able to just use `sort($array)` or `natsort($array)`

Comment: It needs to be sorted by the timestamp portion.

Comment: Then you probably need to look into [`usort()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: `natsort($array)` will not work because I do not want SNAP_CH04... sorted. Natural Sort tends to sort the channel numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `usort` function which let's you define a custom function to compare the strings. Here is how it could work:

```
<?php

function timestamp_cmp($a, $b) {
    $first = substr($a, 10);
    $second = substr($b, 10);
    return strnatcmp($first, $second);
} 
$array = Array ( 
    'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_18_11_05_62777.jpg', 
    'SNAP_CH01_2016_05_15_18_05_38_63588.jpg', 
    'SNAP_CH02_2016_05_15_18_05_13_38387.jpg', 
    'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_15_55_28_52502.jpg',  
    'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_14_52_46_26039.jpg',  
    'SNAP_CH03_2016_05_15_14_52_39_18421.jpg',  
    'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_14_51_34_19005.jpg', 
    'SNAP_CH02_2016_05_15_14_51_25_9874.jpg', 
    'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_06_12_49_23707.jpg', 
    'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_05_03_09_38176.jpg',  
    'SNAP_CH04_2016_05_15_03_33_27_29791.jpg', 
    'SNAP_CH03_2016_05_15_01_59_29_27941.jpg' 
);

usort($array,'timestamp_cmp');
```

**Note:** If you are on PHP 5.3+, you can do this:

```
usort($array,function($a, $b) {
    $first = substr($a, 10);
    $second = substr($b, 10);
    return strnatcmp($first, $second);
});
```

Comment: So how does your function work? It compares the first stored item to the second stored item in the array then strcmp() compares the string?

Comment: @NewbTechGuy The function strips the first 10 characters from the first and second item  and then calls strcmp to compare them. This function gets called each time two items need to be sorted in the sorting algorithm.

Comment: @NewbTechGuy The custom function is supposed to return -1 if the first item is less than the second, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if the second item is greater than the first. Since strcmp already does that, I just need to call that function after I strip the characters we don't need.

Comment: @NewbTechGuy One thing to note is that this code assumes that the channel number portion will always be 10 characters long (including the second underscore).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're ok with sorting the included "SNAP_CH_04" part of the name, you can just use `sort()` to sort the array with no conversion whatsoever.

```
sort($array);
```

If you need to strip that part out, you can use `substr` then `sort()`, like this:

```
for ($a = 0; $a < count($array); $a++)
{
    $array[$a] = substr($array,10);
}

sort($array);
```

Comment: 1. The scope you're using doesn't modify the original array, only the `$a` variable inside the `foreach`, 2. This sorts the original array, and doesn't provide a reference back to the original filenames. Changing the filenames is no good to anyone.

Comment: You're right, I saw that as soon as I posted the original answer.  I changed it to modify the array then sort it, but I think that's probably not the best approach either.  `usort()` is probably the best way to go here.

Comment: Yeah the above foreach destroys the original array without sorting it. :/

Comment: FYI `foreach ($array as &$a)` would have worked too, you just need to use the reference

Comment: You know, it's interesting.  I learn as much or more by answering other people's questions as I do asking my own, lol.